# how to get code and message node value from given json message in c#

Tags: c#, json, .net

Need to get value of code and message

```
{
    "status":null,
    "msg":null,
    "txn":[
        {
            "code":"0",
            "message":"valid.",
            "match":"100",
            "name":null,
            "number":"02100172117301",
            "id":"01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
data = JObject.Parse(yourJson);
string code = data.txn[0].code;
string message = data.txn[0].message;
```